# Can I create computed columns in SQLite?

Tags: sqlite, calculated-columns

What would be the syntax (if it's possible), for example, to create a table called `Car_Model` that has a foreign key to a table `Car_Make`, and give `Car_Make` a column which is the number of `Car_Models` that exist of that `Car_Make`.

(If this seems trivial or homework-like it's because I am just playing with some python at home trying to recreate a problem I was having at work.  We use MS-SQL at work.)

Answer (score 39):

Update: As of version **3.31.0** (released on 2020-01-22), [SQLite supports computed columns](https://www.sqlite.org/draft/releaselog/3_31_0.html) so the answer below applies to versions prior to 3.31.0

SQLite doesn't supported computed columns.

However your problem can be solved with a relatively simple SQL Query, you can then create a view to make it appear like a table with the extra computed columns.

```
SELECT Car_Make.Name, Count(*) AS Count 
FROM Car_Make, Car_Model 
WHERE Car_Make.Id = Car_Model.Make 
GROUP BY Car_Make.Name
```

This should return a table similar to the following

```
Name      Count
----      -----
Nissan    5
Toyota    20
Ford      10
```

Answer (score 16):

> *Can I create computed columns in SQLite?*

Yes, it is possible. This feature was added on 2020-01-22 - **SQLite 3.31.0**

> [Generated Columns](https://sqlite.org/gencol.html)
>
> Generated columns (also sometimes called "computed columns") are columns of a table whose values are a function of other columns in the same row. Generated columns can be read, but their values can not be directly written. The only way to change the value of a generated columns is to modify the values of the other columns used to calculate the generated column.
>
> ```
> CREATE TABLE t1(
>    a INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
>    b INT,
>    c TEXT,
>    d INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS (a*abs(b)) VIRTUAL,
>    e TEXT GENERATED ALWAYS AS (substr(c,b,b+1)) STORED
> );
> ```

**Important:**

> The expression of a generated column may only reference constant
> literals and columns within the same row, and may only use scalar
> deterministic functions. **The expression may not use subqueries,
> aggregate functions, window functions, or table-valued functions.**
>
> **The expression of a generated column may refer to other generated
> columns in the same row**, but no generated column can depend upon
> itself, either directly or indirectly.

It means that you cannot create a computed column in a way it will depend on other tables as stated in original question. So the viable solutions are view or trigger as already proposed.

Comment: Parenthesis for computed formula are important, otherway it does not work for me. Also, I suggest to read further about optional keywords "VIRTUAL" and "STORED". It might be important on the application.

Comment: @TraxidusWolf The parenthesis for computed formula are already present in the code sample: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/blOSP70R).

Answer (score 5):

You may apply a trigger to do that. This case, I apply a division between two fields.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [tUnitPrice] AFTER UPDATE OF [Price], [Qty] ON [tArticles] BEGIN
    UPDATE [tArticles]
    SET    [UnitPrice] = [tArticles].[Price] / [tArticles].[Qty]
    WHERE [rowId] = [NEW].[RowId]; END;
```