# Are there any in-memory databases that support computed columns?

Tags: database, in-memory, calculated-columns, in-memory-database

We have a SQL 2005/2008 database that has a table with a computed column. We're using the computed column as a discriminator in NHibernate so having it in the database is proving to be very useful.

In order to gain the benefits of faster integration tests, I'd like to be able to run our integration tests against an in-memory database such as SQLite or SQL CE. But I don't think either of those support the computed column.

Are there any other solutions to my problem? I have complete access to the database and can modify it if there's a better solution available. I've seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1124695/can-i-create-computed-columns-in-sqlite) that suggests using a view instead of a computed column, is this the best alternative?

Answer (score 1):

What I did was added the computed column to the DataTable when loading the table from SqlCe. I stored the definition of the computed DataColumn in a "configuration" table stored in the database. I was able to do complex calculations that depended on a "chain" of tables, where each table performed a simplier function of a more complex function. (The last table in the chain contained the results.) I used SqlCe because one table of five contained 15 million rows. Too much data for the in-memory data sets of ADO.NET. (I had a requirement of using local client based calculations before posting to server.)