# populate a column with a value based on value of other column alter table sql

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table `'Data'` with a column `'Date'`

I need to add another column called flag and populate it with 0 if the date is less than 2 years from current date and populate it with 1 if the date is more than 2 years from current date.

I did it by adding column using alter table and using update set statement as below

```
alter table data add flag INTEGER constraint flag_value check (flag in(0,1));
```

Is there a way to do this using just one alter table statement without using update set?

Comment: Will this rule always be true or does it only define the default value? For example, could you make `Flag` a computed column whose value is determined by the `Date` column? If so, we may need to know which database product you're using.

Comment: yes, it is computed based on date value and can be defaulted based on the date value. Im using SQLite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to do this using just one alter table statement without using update set?

Not in sqlite, which [does not support computed columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1124695/can-i-create-computed-columns-in-sqlite) and there is no way to run a default `UPDATE` via an `ALTER TABLE` statement.

You could use the view approach from the linked question, or do as you've done and issue separate `ALTER TABLE` and `UPDATE` statements.