# How to split a string into a new column in SQLite3 command line?

Tags: string, sqlite

I am constructing a simple table in SQLite3 using the following .sql script:

```
drop table if exists projects;

CREATE TABLE projects(
  "project_number" TEXT,
  "project_manager" TEXT
);

insert into projects ("project_manager", "project_number")
values ("Bob", "11204568-001");
insert into projects ("project_manager", "project_number")
values ("Bill", "11204568-002");
insert into projects ("project_manager", "project_number")
values ("Jack", "11204568-003");
insert into projects ("project_manager", "project_number")
values ("Jill", "11204000");
insert into projects ("project_manager", "project_number")
values ("Fred", "11204569");
insert into projects ("project_manager", "project_number")
values ("Nancy", "11204569-003");
```

I then add a column to this table called `main_project_number` using the `alter table` statement:

`alter table projects add column "main_project_number"  integer;`

I would then like to populate this new column with only the prefix of the the `project_number_column`, such that I get a result like this:

```
project_number        project_manager  main_project_number
--------------------  ---------------  -------------------
11204568-001          Bob              11204568
11204568-002          Bill             11204568
11204568-003          Jack             11204568
11204000              Jill             11204000
11204569              Fred             11204569
11204569-003          Nancy            11204569
```

So I tried an `update` statement with some sqlite string functions as defined [here](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-string-functions/):

`update projects set main_project_number =  (select substr("project_number",  0, instr("project_number", "-")) from projects);`

This produced the following result, however, which is not what I want...:

```
project_number        project_manager  main_project_number
--------------------  ---------------  -------------------
11204568-001          Bob              11204568
11204568-002          Bill             11204568
11204568-003          Jack             11204568
11204000              Jill             11204568
11204569              Fred             11204568
11204569-003          Nancy            11204568
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update should refer to specific row:

```
update projects 
set main_project_number = 
    CASE WHEN instr("project_number", "-") > 0 
         THEN substr("project_number", 0, instr("project_number", "-"))
         ELSE "project_number"
    END
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=f6a5068f58f8b970e09f33404838d3d3)**

---

If you are using SQLite 3.31.0 and above I suggest to use [generated columns](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59916205/5070879) to avoid running update.

```
ALTER TABLE projects
ADD COLUMN main_project_number TEXT GENERATED ALWAYS AS
  (CASE WHEN instr("project_number", "-") > 0 
             THEN substr("project_number", 0, instr("project_number", "-"))
             ELSE "project_number"
        END) VIRTUAL;
```

Comment: If generated columns are the preferred sqlite alternative then I would like to go with a generated column. Would you be so kind as to take a look at my attempt? I have added it to my edit to the original question...

Comment: Never mind, I was missing a comma... generated column works very well

Comment: If you would like to add the generated column alternative in your above answer I will gladly accept it...

Comment: Hmmm.. I was under the impression that the generated column should only be declared upon table creation... I guess that doesn't have to be the case....

Answer (score 1):

If the column project_number does not have leading `0`s you can do it like this:

```
update projects 
set main_project_number =  project_number + 0;
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qrQJR9DHQuXheq2ETzDLn/1).

Comment: What will happen if project number contains letters/"." or any non digit character?

Comment: The column's name is `project_number` so it is safe to assume that there are not any non-digit chars except `-`. The only problem would be if there are leading 0s which I mention in my answer.

Comment: In my dataset there are no non-digit characters except for `-`, so this could indeed be a viable solutaion. However I agree with @Lukasz Szozda that it is a bit of a hacky solution, and may lack generality in certain cases...

Comment: This is not hacky. It is based on your sample data and it is far more efficient.