# Create new column in existing SQLite3 table

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a table shown below

| Id | Retweet_count | Fav_count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | 8 |
| 2 | 3 | 3 |
| 3 | 4 | 1 |
| 4 | 0 | 1 |

How do i create a new column in the table called "Total_interaction", where it shows the values of the sum of both Retweet_count and Fav_count like this.

| Id | Retweet_count | Fav_count | Total_interaction |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | 8 | 13 |
| 2 | 3 | 3 | 6 |
| 3 | 4 | 1 | 5 |
| 4 | 0 | 1 | 1 |

Currently i have my connection to my database as shown below.

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('tweets_data.sqlite')
cur = conn.cursor()
```

Comment: Read about [Generated columns](https://www.sqlite.org/gencol.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create a new column with the already present columns then you can use generated columns.

```
ALTER TABLE your_table_name
  ADD Total_interaction INTEGER GENERATED ALWAYS
    AS (Retweet_count + Fav_count);
```

Replace your_table_name with your Table name.
You can read more about it [here](https://database.guide/add-a-generated-column-to-a-table-in-sqlite/)

Comment: This might not fully answer what OP needs. This would just create a new column without any values.

Comment: ADDED changes @sushanth

Comment: You may also look at [Can I create computed column in SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1124695/can-i-create-computed-columns-in-sqlite)